# Cloud Dataflow streaming, stop when idle to save money?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have an application where users can vote for something.

I want my application to scale up so I've decided to aggregate counters stored in Firestore using Cloud Dataflow.

I've set up a Dataflow job of type **streaming** so I it can listen for pubsub topics whenever a user vote for something.

Sometimes I have thousands user inputs a day, sometimes I got a few hundreds... is there any solution to "pause" the job when it's not receiving pubsub messages for a while?

Currently, my dataflow job is always RUNNING and i'm afraid this will cost me a lot of money.

If someone can help me to understand billing with streaming job, w'd appreciate

Here's my Python pipeline :

```
def run(argv=None):
    # Config
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Output PubSub Topic
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output_topic', required=True)
    # Input PubSub Topic
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input_topic', required=True)

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # Pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    # Pipeline process
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        # Counting votes
        def count_votes(contestant_votes):
            (contestant, votes) = contestant_votes
            return (contestant, sum(votes))

        # Format data to a fake object (used to be parsed by the CF)
        def format_result(contestant_votes):
            (contestant, votes) = contestant_votes
            return '{ "contestant": %s, "votes": %d }' % (contestant, votes)

        transformed = (p
                       | 'Receive PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic)
                       .with_output_types(bytes)
                       | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
                       | 'Pair with one' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
                       | 'Apply window of time' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(30, 0))
                       | 'Group by contestant' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                       | 'Count votes' >> beam.Map(count_votes)
                       | 'Format to fake object string' >> beam.Map(format_result)
                       | 'Transform to PubSub base64 string' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))
                       .with_output_types(bytes))

        # Trigger a the output PubSub topic with the message payload
        transformed | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)

        result = p.run()
        result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

[image: Job config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your cost question: With the worker you are currently using, it will cost you around $250USD (depending on your PD usage over the month).

There is currently no wait to force dataflow to "idle" or scale to 0 workers. The minimum you can have is 1.

This being said there are a few routes you can take to try to minimize cost.

If your worker isn't under much load, and you want the simplest option, you can use a less powerful worker (n1-standard-1 [~USD $77.06] or n1-standard-2 [~USD $137.17]). https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=3bbedf2f-8bfb-41db-9923-d3a5ef0c0250 (if you see I have all 3 variations added, using 430GB PD which I saw in your photo).

If you need the compute power, you could switch to using a cron based dataflow job as discussed here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions. With this, you should likely read from a subscription instead of a topic so you can retain the messages until you kick off your job.